# Intellij IDEA 2020.1 Copy Resources to Output with Package

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 CE. I have a non-Maven Java project that builds and works fine. I use the built-in build system. The resources are all correctly copied from the source resources folder to the project's output directory; however, since I use a package, e.g., org.acme, I'd like the resources to actually be copied to the output/org/acme folder, so that they end up with the .class files.

Is this possible? Do I need to perform a post-build step? Other?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 4):

The good people at JetBrains helped me out on this one, so I thought I'd share it here.

To copy Java project resources to a directory relative to the project output directory (where the *.class* files go by default), use the Relative Output Path for the directory marked as your resources directory.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html

For example, let's suppose you have a Java project and you put your classes into a package called *org.acme.* Let's also assume your resources are in a *resources/* directory and that your project's output directory is called *target/.*

What will happen by default is that your *.class* files will end up in *target/org/acme/*, but your resources will end up in *target/*. If you want to copy your resources to the same place as your *.class* files (it makes loading them easier at times), you can set your Relative Output Path to *org/acme/*

In the IntelliJ IDE, from the main menu:

- File -> Project Structure
- Select *Modules* from the left-hand pane
- Select *Sources* from the main panel
- Select your *resources/* directory
- Click on the pencil icon next to the resources directory
- Add your Relative Output Path

Next time the project builds, the resources will be copied to this relative path under the primary output directory.

I hope this was useful!

John

Comment: If you ever need to do the equivalent of this in Maven, or just want to understand the search process for resources better, the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other has useful information.